# Trying to display 2 tables data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables

Table name `Dist`.

```
NAME|Phone|ID 
----------------
Oakley|555-555|1
Maui|666-666|2
lux|777-7777|3
```

Table name `Patientacct`.

```
Name|prescription|id|orderfrom
-------------------------------
bob|20-20|1|oakley
billy|15-20|2|Oakley, Maui
kim|20-20|3|Lux
```

I'm looking for a display like

```
Oakley
--------------------
Bob
Billy
```

```
Maui
------------------
Billy
```

```
Lux
--------------
kim
```

Trials so far

```
SELECT *
FROM `dist`
JOIN `patientacct` ON patientacct.dist LIKE CONCAT('%', `dist`.name ,'%')
GROUP BY `dist`.name
```

This showed only 1 dist

If I drop the group by example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `dist`
JOIN `patientacct` ON patientacct.dist LIKE CONCAT('%', `dist`.name ,'%')
```

I get the record twice so what I need is somewhere between the two. I'm extremely new to joins so be easy when explaining.

Comment: You need to make a many-to-many table with all the possible relations, that actually uses some indexes, this is just pure torture man...

Comment: i dont know how considering a person can have a purchase from more than one!

Comment: we can't do all your work for you, but only steer you in the right direction, because you are lacking some pretty basic knowledge - google many-to-many database tables, foreign keys and indexes - and you can't get the desired output just by querying, you will have to format it with php afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

you must change your tables structure and you need to add a relation table with this values:

orders:

```
dist_id, patientacct_id PRIMARY_KEY(dist_id, patientacct_id)
```

Comment: given that I make these changes I still want just one dist to show and all the people with that dist to show underneath, How is this possible?

Comment: I gave an example above of how i wanted the info to display. This might be some php work as well as sql!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make the table structure relational. Have a primary auto_increment value in each table and use the primary key from the Dlist foreign key to Patientacct. This way, a simple join would fetch the record you have wanted.

Regarding the display, what do you mean you don't want record twice. Since you are using join, you will get two records for Oakley with the patient Bob and Billy. That's what you wanted and it would be like that by a simple join too in a relational table.

Comment: are you suggesting its not possible to show one dist and all the people with that dist listed underneath?

Comment: and about the relational part. how do i use a key to link one record to several others. as above the record oakley would link to bob and billy?

Comment: If you have the record then display is not the problem. You can use some extra code to display as per your wish. And regarding relation, for instance the dist has record like (1,oakley,555-555,10) then the primary key for oakley is 1. Now in the patientacct table use this key to relate all the patient for this doctor like (2,billy,15-20,2,1) where the final value 1 is the foreign key of table dist. Now for other patient use the same foreign key like (3,bob,20-20,4,1). Now since there are two value of 1 as a foreign key in table patientacct, by the simple inner join you will have those records.

Comment: The table structure should be like dist(dist_id,name, phone, ID). Does not know what ID mean in your case, so included. dist_id is the primary auto_increment. The table structure for patientacct(patient_id, name, prescription, id, dist_id) Here dist_id is the foreign key from dist table and patient_id is the primary auto_increment. Hope this helps!

Comment: And if you are using php, then use php to display as per your wish. Pull the required data using mysql and then use php to display as per your wish.