# Displaying mysql values as category and items

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following two tables in my mysql database.

Table Name: groups

```
 id    group_name
 1     Garments
 2     Computer Accessories 
 3     Food
```

Table Name: account

```
 id     group_id    account_name
 1         1        T-shirt
 2         1        Jeans
 3         2        Motherboard
 4         2        Mouse
```

What I am trying to display is like following:

```
Garments 
      T-Shirt
       Jeans
Computer Accessories
       Motherboard
       Mouse
Food
```

I have tried the following query but could not make the output like above

```
 SELECT group_name,accounts.account_name,accounts.id FROM `groups`
 LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.group_id=groups.id
```

If I run the query it displays like following:

```
  Garments                T-Shirt
  Garments                Jeans
  Computer Accessories    Motherboard
  Computer Accessories    Mouse
  Food                    NULL
```

Could you please show me how to display the output like I have mentioned above. Just for your information I am using Codeigniter.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I think your problem is quite similar to this thread.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183658/trying-to-display-2-tables-data/11187774#11187774

Comment: What do you mean by "display the output"?  A database query alone is going to give you data in tabular form, which you've shown us.  How you display that data to the user is up to you.  How are you displaying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query for this purpose

```
select
  group_name as Group_name,
  group_concat(account_name) as Accounts
from garments
  left join account
    on account.group_id = garments.id
group by garments.group_name
```

Use group concat. This will display this result then you can explode accounts on php end

```
Group_name              Accounts
Computer Accessories    Motherboard,Mouse
Food                    (NULL)
Garments                T-shirt,Jeans
```

Comment: I did forget about the usage of group_concat that you taught me once :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = mysql_query('select * from groups');
while($category = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
{
   $ID = $category['id'];
   $category_name = $category['group_name'];
   echo $category_name;

   $accounts = mysql_query("select * from account where group_id = $ID");
   while($account = mysql_fetch_array($accounts))
   {
      $account_name = $account['account_name'];
      echo 'TAB TAB TAB '.$account_name;
   }
}
```

You can place Cateogory_name and account_name into their container's and make output better .